# Button needs to be clicked twice (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Background**: Trying to build a fullscreen menu for mobile devices on a one page site.

**Problem**: The #handle div needs to be clicked 2 times for action. I have tried to use following in different ways but i seem to implement it wrong in some way:
*live / die,
bind / unbind,
on / off,
delegate / undelegate*.

I don't understand how i should solve my problem. Sorry for bad id-names on some divs.

**HTML**

```
      <div id="overlay">
            <input type="checkbox" id="op"></input>

                <div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc">
                    <label for="op"></label>
                        <div id="nav">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="homescroll" class="overlayli">Home</li>
                                <li class="servscroll" class="overlayli">Services</li>
                                <li class="workscroll" class="overlayli">Work</li>
                                <li class="aboutscroll" class="overlayli">About</li>
                                <li class="contactscroll" class="overlayli">Contact</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>
      </div>
```

**Jquery**
When li is clicked the user gets scrolled down the page and the menu is hidden:
If the user now wants to open the menu again it needs to be clicked 2 times for action.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {  
         $('li').hover(             
              function () {
                $('li', this).fadeIn();
              },
              function () {                 
                $('li', this).fadeOut();
              }
            );
        $(".aboutcroll").off().on('click', function() {

          $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#aboutdummy").offset().top
            }, 800);                
            $("#overlay").hide();
            $("#handle").on('click'); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

When #handle is clicked the overlay fullscreen menu will open:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#handle").off().on('click', function() {
                $("#overlay").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i find it very hard to identify what you problem really is. perhaps you can edit the question to go through each click, then show what code you think is firing and what you expect it to do and what it is actually doing

Comment: You have multiple class attributes on each `li`. That means the browser remembers either the first, or the second, but not both class names. Use one class with the two names separated by spaces, e.g. `class="homescroll overlayli"`. Not sure if that has anything to do with this particular problem though.

Comment: Just changed this. Not solving the problem. Thx though!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your **#handle onClick function**
In your code you are using

```
$("#handle").off().on('click', function() {
        $("#overlay").show();
});
```

Here **.off()** is removing the event listener on the first click! Try removing .off()

Also for the scrolling, you can use the following code (which is also **without .off()**)

```
$("SELECTOR").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top
    }, 500);
     return false;
});
```

Hope this works for you! And If it doesn't it would better if you can share your code via jsFiddle or CodePen.

Comment: This sadly does not seem to solve my problem either. What is the return false for?

Comment: Can you give a jsFiddle of your code so that we can get a better insight to your problem? And "return false" is to stop propagating event to it's child elements. It is similar to event.returnValue = false (IE); or event.stopPropagation() or setting event.cancelBubble = true (IE)